# Where can I find a Mini-ITX template?

Tags: motherboard, mini-itx

I'm considering a custom case build based on mini-ITX.  However, I can't find any reference containing the board template (other than the simple board dimensions).

Specifically I'm missing:

- Mounting hole locations
- Backplate positioning
- Any other specific measurements which must be taken into account

Can anyone point me in the right direction for the standard spec with annotated template?

Answer (score 1):

This protocase document probably has most of what you want:

http://www.protocase.com/pdf/How_to_design_enclosures_for_motherboard_based_systems_092010.pdf